# SQL Server: Batch Requests/sec showed increase in performance, but performance actually decreased

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, perfmon

We are currently on SQL Server 2005, with a plan to move to SQL 2012. To make this move we have to test new database drivers for the application (Java). We performed 2 load tests using the 2 different drivers.

Test 1

- Transactions/sec  = 9400
- Batch Requests/sec = 2400

Test 2

- Transactions/sec = 7200
- Batch Requests/Sec = 6000

What I am interested in is why the massive increased in batch request/sec in test2, even though there was an overall drop in trans/sec (note that the front end performance mirrored the drop in trans/sec between the 2 tests). If it wasn't for us monitoring front end performance and trans/sec we would have actually thought we'd seen a 3x improvement in performance, instead of an actual 20% drop in performance.

Any thoughts on what features of the drivers may cause this?

For reference test 1 was performed with I-net Java driver, test 2 was performed with MS JDBC driver.

Comment: Can you post connection strings for each approach? What is being called? Ad Hoc SQL generated from the app or stored procedures? Generally speaking - I've seen better performance with other drivers/jTDS than the MS JDBC - but there are a lot of factors at play.

I also presume there were multiple tests and you've confirmed the isolation of the environment during the test runs.

Comment: Possibly a difference between the way the drivers issue queries? Maybe the newer drivers are more likely to submit batches separately. Without seeing the nature of your workload it's tough to guess, but Mike is also right that there may be differences in connection string properties, as opposed to just the driver version.

Comment: Also look here - it isn't just my isolated testing that has shown jTDS as faster, apparently ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848213/why-is-jtds-faster-than-microsoft-jdbc-driver

Comment: What? Higher batch requests/sec doesn't mean improved performance -- it's a measure of server activity. It doesn't surprise me at all that tx/sec dropped as batch requests/sec increased.